# Is there any kind of API/RSS feed I can tap into to find CefSharp updates, particularly security updates?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

We use Cefsharp in a project, but need to be able to keep it up to date, particularly with security updates.

This project will be deployed to most PCs in the organisation, but is not expected to have constant development attention: which is to say, there won't be project managers and developers working on it day-to-day most of the time. As such, I'm concerned that security updates could get "lost" when the project is in it's dormant stages.

Is there anywhere I can programatically check for Cefsharp/chromium embedded  updates, in order to either automatically update the project, or alert someone that it needs to be updated?

Comment: Why not asking on their official site?

Comment: Are you using Nuget as your source?  Every package has an atom feed linked in the lower right of the page - here's the one for [CefSharp.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Common/atom.xml) for instance.  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

See the releases page:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases

That page has its RSS/Atom here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases.atom

You can also subscribe to be notified of new releases via email by clicking the Watch button in top right corner and choosing "Releases only". Check your Github account whether it's configured to send emails.